# Contact Form 7 Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a website that uses contact form 7 plugin for my contact form.

I added a JQuery function that will focus the first empty fields before clicking the submit button.

What I want to do is when i clicked the submit button with all fields are empty, what I want is to focus the first empty fields after clicking the submit button.

What JQuery function should i use? right now this is my JS:

```
$( ".col-form3").find( "input:first").focus();
```

NOTE: The jquery above is executing properly before clicking the submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will do it like that way :

HTML :

```
<input type="text" name="t1" value="">
<input type="text" name="t2" value="">
<input type="text" name="t3" value="">
<input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="button">
```

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>     $("#button").on('click',function(){
>       $("input:not(:checkbox,:button)").each(function(){       
>       if(!$(this).val() ) {
>         $(this).focus();
>         return false;
>           }
>       });
>     });
> });
> ```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eb7a9jgm/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work for you :

```
$(".wpcf7-submit").click(function(){
    $(".wpcf7-submit").ajaxComplete(function(){
        if($(".wpcf7-response-output").hasClass("wpcf7-validation-errors")){
            $(".wpcf7-form-control").each(function(){
                if($(this).val().length === 0){
                    $(this).focus();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Tell me if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this java script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){     
jQuery(".wpcf7-submit").ajaxComplete(function(){           
var check = jQuery( ".wpcf7-form").find( ".wpcf7-not-valid:eq( 0 )");
if(check)
{
check.focus();
}
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: you can try and replace var check = jQuery( ".wpcf7-form").find( ".wpcf7-not-valid:eq( 0 )"); with var check = jQuery( ".wpcf7-form").find( ".wpcf7-not-valid:first");